# Does the Array algorithm have an fail? / What is NewTarget?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The question concerns the Array constructor algorithm.
https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array-constructor-array

The outcome of the algorithm is not quite clear:

> 3. If NewTarget is undefined, let newTarget be the active function object, else let newTarget be NewTarget.

This applies to the case when we call this constructor as a function and the *active function object* is **null** (it is **null** when we call it from under Script or Module).

Go to the line:

> 4. Let proto be? GetPrototypeFromConstructor (newTarget, "% ArrayPrototype%").

Go to the algorithm GetPrototypeFromConstructor and find the following:

> 2. Assert: IsCallable (constructor) is true.

There can not be **null**, because null is not callable.

We make one of the conclusions:

1. We misunderstood something.
2. Specification Error

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Pointy what you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand what question you are asking. What exactly is it that you think is "wrong"?

Comment: @Pointy `Assert: IsCallable (constructor) is true.` But here we have **null**. There can not be **null**, because **null** is not callable.

Comment: Why do you think it's `null`? The `active function object` won't be `null`.

Comment: @Pointy https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#table-22 component Function.
`If this execution context is evaluating the code of a function object, then the value of this component is that function object. If the context is evaluating the code of a Script or Module, the value is null.`

Comment: But the `Array` constructor is a function object.

Comment: I would of course be willing to agree that the way the spec is written in general could not be much more obtuse.

Comment: @Pointy If I understand you correctly, in this case the active function object applies to the Array itself, right?

Comment: Not the array *object*, the `Array` constructor function (which is also an object of course)

Comment: @Pointy I also meant that active function object is applied to the constructor Array that we call as a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That confusing bit about what `NewTarget` is I think the key to the puzzle. What that rule means is basically:

- If `Array` is invoked as a plain function, then the value of `newTarget` is the `Array` constructor
- If `Array` is invoked as `new Array`, then the value of `newTarget` is also the `Array` constructor

Why?  Well, when the `[[Construct]]` operation is invoked, the second argument gives `newTarget`. Calls to the `[[Construct]]` operation pass the constructor function itself as that argument. However, a plain call to `Array` does not involve that operation; it's just a plain `[[Call]]`. So in that case `NewTarget` is `undefined`, and so the rule says that `newTarget` is the "active function context".  Because we're talking about what goes on in the `Array` constructor, it's clearly true that the active function context is that function; otherwise why would we be reading that chapter of the spec?

Why is it worded that way?  I have no idea.